# Calling custom function inside UIStoryboard-instantiated UIViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I think my problem is best expressed by first giving an outline of what I'm trying to accomplish and then giving my implementation, followed by the problem I've ran into.

### Goal

I'm attempting to make a profile page within my iOS app that can be instantiated from the Storyboard, given a user ID, and then fetch all the meta data from the server.

### Implementation

In my storyboard, I have designed the `ViewController` and linked the `ImageViews`, `buttons` et cetera as `@IBOutlets`. The user's (person using the app.) homepage is instantiated by the Storyboard, but the rest are pushed in by code. In order to grab the data, I have a function `loadDataForID(ID: Int)`

Now, the problem I have is that [`#instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:) returns a `UIViewController` that I cannot upcast to my `ProfileViewController`, in order to call the data fetching function.

So, my next thought was to manually create the `ProfileViewController`, call the helper function and then push the view, but then I ran into another problem: since all the views are `@IBOutlets`, and this controller wasn't instantiated by the Storyboard, they're all nil references.

As I'm new to iOS development, I'm almost certain there's a better way to implement this, but I'm completely stuck; I don't know where to go from here. Is there a way around these issues or should I do things a different way?

Comment: why don't you just downcast the view controller your got from instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier to ProfileViewController?
such as `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID") as! ProfileViewController `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String)` as `ProfileViewController` as shown into below code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewControllerID") as! ProfileViewController

//Now you can access property of ProfileViewController here

self.presentViewController(profileVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Wow. This is absolutely embarrassing. I had tried this before, but I accidentally had "!" AFTER ProfileViewController, not before it. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Comment: Ah. It fixed the problem of not being able to call the helper function, but the views are still nil. How do I get around that?

Comment: Can you share demo project?

Comment: You moved me in the right direction, and I believe my current problem is unrelated to the specifics of my question, so I'm going to give you the answer: Upcasting. Thanks!